# C# date time picker conversion

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am trying to make a program that will store the date in the database with the format of dd/MM/yyyy.I googled and saw same results. I tried coding it but it doesnt work. The input date is in the pattern of dd/MM/yy using datetimepicker's custom format. After manipulating the string a little bit to remove padding zeroes, the string returned is MM/dd/yyyy.

Here is my code

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Cdate.Text + "CDATE"); //shows dd/MM/yyyy
            string[] datecut = new string[4];

            datecut = Cdate.Text.Split('/');
            DateTime cdate = DateTime.ParseExact(datecut[0].PadLeft(2, '0') + '/' + datecut[1].PadLeft(2, '0') + '/' + datecut[2], "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            EC.setCDate(cdate.ToShortDateString());
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(cdate.ToShortDateString()); //shows MM/dd/yyyy

            datecut = Cdate.Text.Split('/');
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datecut[0].PadLeft(2, '0') + '/' + datecut[1].PadLeft(2, '0') + '/' + datecut[2], "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            EC.setDate(date.ToShortDateString());
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(date.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: What kind of database?

Answer (score 4):

> store the date in the database with the format of dd/MM/yyyy

No, no, **NO**. Your database will have a data type specifically dedicated to date fields. You should use that type. This date type does *not* store the date value in any human-readable format. It will store the date in a compact binary format. Your query or database tool only shows you a human-readable format for convenience.

If you can give an example of where you save the date to the database, and what kind of database you're using, we can show you how to do this without formatting your date at all.

Comment: If there is not a VERY specific reason why he is doing this I agree, my answer was for the question at hand but user1548960 Joel is right there is no reason to alter the format of your date if its going to SQL just pass along the DateTime object to your command parameter and let it fly.  If you want to store that format for some requirements sake then make it a varchar column and pass long what I did with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

String Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

Generally you use the DateTime.TryParse method to parse a string. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)  Once you have the string as a DateTime object, you can print it back out however you like using DateTime.toString() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a datepicker and you are attempting to work with the string representation of the selected date.  If that's the case I would not do that.  Date picker has a property called value which is a DateTime Object representing the chosen date, in which you could literatlly pass to your EC.setDate Method like so.

```
EC.setDate(dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```